# Geolocation statistics

Tags: support

I assume  that geolocation statistics for a given site -- i.e. statistics about the countries from which users and/or readers visit a site -- might be known to SE.

But would it be true to say that it is not published anywhere? Not in the "Site Analytics", not in data explorer, not anywhere?

And furthermore that SE wouldn't disclose this if asked?

I ask because there's a user who thinks the information might be relevant to community-building or something somehow.

Comment: Well - SE does in log IPs, and you can roughly guess locations from there. The information is there

Comment: Yes I assume that SE has raw data, but are you saying the users can read SE's log files, or, where might users find such IP information?

Comment: Users can set their location in their [profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell?tab=profile) and looking at SEDE I believe you can find that field there too. But if users chose not to disclose it, regular users are out of options...

Comment: uhm, no. But it may be worth asking for statistics ;p

Comment: I would simply ask them with a good reason why you want the information. I guess they used such information when they launched Russia.SO, and it could help for site like French language. They might just answer a percentage to not give the exact number, but to know how much visitor are for french country in example, as it could help to know if the site is viable in the long term.